# Tools->Environment->Keyboard assign do not take effect on Edit.Cut (Ctrl+X - ReSharper.ReSharper_BookmarksBookmarksMenu)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, cut

I'm using visual studio community edition with resharper. I want to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shorcut to `Edit`.Cut from `Resharper.BookmarksMenu`.

I applied Visual Studio scheme from `Extensions->ReSharper->Keyboard & Menus` then saved.
I assigned (Default)Edit.Cut as Global <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

But the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shortcut continues to open the bookmarks menu of ReSharper.

[image: ReSharper]
[image: Visual Studio]

Comment: If you click on the "Shortcut currently used by" combo-box for the "Ctrl+X" shortcut, will the "ReSharper_BookmarksBookmarksMenu" action still be mapped to this shortcut for the "Text Editor scope"? If so, you need to map the "Ctrl+X" shortcut to the "Edit.Cut" action in the "Textr Editor" scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you  Alexander Kurakin. I mapped the "Ctrl+X" shortcut to the "Edit.Cut" action in the "Text Editor" scope. Now it is working.

I solved it for Edit.Cut like this:

Shortcuts for selected command: Ctrl+X (Text Editor)
Use new shortcut in: Text Editor
Press shortcut keys: Ctrl+X

Than Assign and it is working.